# Unrecognized option 'c:v' ffmpeg error for converting videos to H264

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

I told my server to upgrade to latest version of ffmpeg and they told me they did and I have the latest version that is 2.2.1 . 
I test several codes to convert a video to x264 , here is the one ;

```
passthru("$ffmpegpath -i aatest/a.AVI -c:v libx264 -c:a libfaac -preset veryslow -qp 0 aatest/output.mp4 2>&1");
```

the result

> FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
>   built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat
>   4.4.5-6) configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab libavutil 50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1 libavcodec 52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
>   libavformat 52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2 libavdevice 52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
>   libavfilter 1.19. 0 / 1.19. 0 libswscale 0.11. 0 / 0.11. 0 libpostproc
>   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0 [mpeg4 @ 0x1111960]Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected [mpeg4 @ 0x1111960]frame skip 8 Input #0,
>   avi, from 'aatest/a.AVI': Duration: 00:02:04.04, start: 0.000000,
>   bitrate: 885 kb/s Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 480x360 [PAR 4:3
>   DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, 2
>   channels, s16, 128 kb/s Unrecognized option 'c:v'

the last line says "Unrecognized option 'c:v'"

What should I do ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 17):

For newer versions like mine 0.8.12 use `-vcodec` instead of `-c:v`

Comment: That's libav's ffmpeg rather than ffmpeg's ffmpeg.

Answer (score 7):

The ffmpeg version looks wrong (0.6.5). Perhaps that is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the version numbers. It looks like you have a problem with your path that's putting the older version before the one you just installed.

Do a `which ffmpeg` to see where the old one is coming from. From there you'll want to either uninstall/delete the old one or rearrange your PATH.